# Conditional on title in template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I can get output on the current page title by doing:

```
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
```

However, how can I use this in a conditional? This doesn't seem to work:

```
{% if title == "Bla" %}
   doing some stuff!
{% endif %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not write it in views?

Comment: In this case, title is a block in your template. If you don't set the variable `title` in your view you will not be able to use this in a conditional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your current syntax is correct according to the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#operator), double check that `title` has the value you think it does.

> **`==` operator**
>   Equality. Example:
>
> `{% if somevar == "x" %}`
>       `This appears if variable somevar equals the string "x"`
>   `{% endif %}`